# env variables works with Metro Bundler but undefined when build with eas react native

Tags: android, react-native, environment-variables, eas

I'm using `"babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables": "^0.4.4"`  when I run

`API_KEY=api-key  AUTH_DOMAIN=mydomain.com  PROJECT_ID=id  STORAGE_BUCKET=bucket.com  MESSAGING_SENDER_ID=123  APP_ID=id  MEASUREMENT_ID=gg expo start -c`

It works, and set my env variables, but when I want to build my app with

`API_KEY=api-key  AUTH_DOMAIN=mydomain.com  PROJECT_ID=id  STORAGE_BUCKET=bucket.com  MESSAGING_SENDER_ID=123  APP_ID=id  MEASUREMENT_ID=gg eas build -p android -e preview --clear-cache`

It doesn't set my env vars values, what I'm doing wrong?

this is my **babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
    plugins: ["transform-inline-environment-variables"],
  };
};
```

and I'm using my env vars to set my firebase connection

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env["API_KEY"],
  authDomain: process.env["AUTH_DOMAIN"],
  projectId: process.env["PROJECT_ID"],
  storageBucket: process.env["STORAGE_BUCKET"],
  messagingSenderId: process.env["MESSAGING_SENDER_ID"],
  appId: process.env["APP_ID"],
  measurementId: process.env["MEASUREMENT_ID"],
};
```